# How to manage two video cards on a laptop (ATI and Intel)?

Tags: graphics, ati, intel-graphics

I have a laptop with two video cards. One ATI and on integrated Intel.

On Windows, I can choose which video card I want to use.

For example, I use the Intel card for normal use and for gaming, I switch to my ATI card for better performance, but a shorter battery life.

In Ubuntu 10.10, only the Intel driver is installed, the ATI driver for my card doesn't work at all and there's heat coming out of my computer all the time, like when I'm playing video games on Windows. I think both cards are active, but only the Intel one is usefull.

How can I solve this by making sure Ubuntu is aware of the two video cards and by disabling my ATI. Or may be I am all wrong about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is not a concrete answer, but I've found a couple links that might be able to help you out:

**1. [Ubuntu Documentation for Hybrid Graphics](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics)**

**2. [Ubuntu forums discussion on the topic.](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1556671)**

**3. [This one is for users with less experience in kernels etc.](http://asusm51ta-with-linux.blogspot.com/)**

I had found other links late last year - if I can find the articles again I will add them to my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Hybrid graphics has improved a bit lately. The Catalyst drivers provide a login/logout switch. Have a look at these websites:
https://launchpad.net/~hybrid-graphics-linux
http://linux-hybrid-graphics.blogspot.com