# Fan not detected by lm-sensors

Tags: fan

My fan is blowing hard, while my cpu temperature is 32 degrees

I tried a lot of things to control my fan.

Changed grub file

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi= pci=noacpi"
```

_

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=\"Linux\""
```

Ran `sensors-detect` :

```
To load everything that is needed, add this to /etc/modules:
#----cut here----
# Chip drivers
coretemp
#----cut here----
If you have some drivers built into your kernel, the list above will
contain too many modules. Skip the appropriate ones!

Do you want to add these lines automatically to /etc/modules? (yes/NO)

Unloading i2c-dev... OK
Unloading i2c-i801... OK
Unloading cpuid... OK
```

Ran `sensors`:

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +34.0°C  (crit = +90.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +34.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
Core 2:       +34.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
```

Ran `sudo start module-init-tools` and `sudo start module-init-tools`

```
module-init-tools stop/waiting
```

As you can see my fan isn't detected.

Running `fancontrol` gives me this:

```
Loading configuration from /etc/fancontrol ...
Error: Can't read configuration file
```

Can you help me, please? I cannot use my laptop now in class.

Thanks in advance.

My **Ubuntu 11.10** system

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 02)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor PCI Express x16 Root Port (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 05)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev 05)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a5)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc Manhattan [Mobility Radeon HD 5400 Series]
01:00.1 Audio device: ATI Technologies Inc Manhattan HDMI Audio [Mobility Radeon HD 5000 Series]
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 02)
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller (rev 01)
7f:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 05)
7f:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 05)
7f:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 05)
7f:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 05)
7f:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 05)
7f:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 05)
```

**EDIT**

Just installed Lubuntu and lm-sensors doesn't have any problems to detect my both my fans.

Comment: COuld you tell us what machine this is?

Comment: Ubuntu 11.10, HP G72

Comment: Can you control your fan via BIOS? Possibly it helps to adjust some settings there ...

Comment: Nope, I've checked it already....

Comment: did you verify the bios settings? there is some specific ones for lower or make it run faster in most newest machines

Comment: You need PWM fans for that feature. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know the source of my problem.

After installing Lubuntu I ran `sensors` and this was the output:

```
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +52.0°C  (crit = +90.0°C)

radeon-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +97.5°C
```

Then I installed the propietary fglrx driver. The output of `sensors` was only

```
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +52.0°C  (crit = +90.0°C)
```

So, the ATI/AMD fglrx driver causes the problem.

Comment: then !,what the solution ?! :)

Comment: lm-sensor can use the radeon kernel module to read the GPU temperature. When you are using fglrx, you are loading a different kernel module (the fglrx), not the radeon module, so you lm-sensor can't read data from a not loaded module. But the fglrx also read this value, but you need to use the aticonfig tool, check the `aticonfig --od-gettemperature` and `aticonfig --pplib-cmd "get temperature 0"`

Comment: also, AFAIK, lm-sensor can't read the fglrx data.

Answer (score 4):

Before using fancontrol you have to generate a configuration using `sudo pwmconfig` from [fancontrol](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=fancontrol) package, which replace [lm-sensors](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=lm-sensors&searchon=names).

You may also find some relevant info at [How to manage two video cards on a laptop (ATI and Intel)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21455/how-to-manage-two-video-cards-on-a-laptop-ati-and-intel)

Answer (score 1):

When the `sensors` doesn't output the processor fan nowadays, you might try to reinstall the processor drivers, it worked for me and I was having huge problems with it.

Check out this answer for intel drivers: https://askubuntu.com/a/767127/494131