# lm-sensors not detect fan

Tags: overheating, fan, temperature

Hello I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04.2 and at first I had problems with overheating. I had to install the drivers for the Nvidia Geforce GT630M card and seems to have been solved.

Anyway, I have the feeling that you still have overheating problems, I installed `lm-sensors` for temperature and after `sudo sensors-detect` I get this:

```
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +53.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 0:         +53.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:         +53.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 2:         +53.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 3:         +53.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
```

Apparently it seems that the temperature is right. However, the heat coming out of the laptop is very hot and if I open more windows chrome, play video in youtube the temperature rises above 60 °C. It may also be because it is very hot in summer but I'm surprised I had never seen my laptop so hot.

Therefore install lm sensors for fan speed if the fan is spinning slower than normal but the problem that I have is that it does not detect me. When I do a sensors-detect this are modules that detects me:

```
# Chip drivers
coretemp
```

I've looked at this forum and many websites possible answers but none has helped me.

Thank you for your attention

Edit with result `sudo lshw -C display,cpu`

```
*-cpu                   
   descripción: CPU
   producto: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3630QM CPU @ 2.40GHz
   fabricante: Intel Corp.
   id físico: 27
   información del bus: cpu@0
   versión: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3630QM CPU @ 2.40GHz
   ranura: SOCKET 0
   tamaño: 2860MHz
   capacidad: 3800MHz
   anchura: 64 bits
   reloj: 100MHz
   capacidades: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms cpufreq
   configuración: cores=4 enabledcores=4 threads=8
  *-display
   descripción: VGA compatible controller
   producto: GF108M [GeForce GT 630M]
   fabricante: NVIDIA Corporation
   id físico: 0
   información del bus: pci@0000:01:00.0
   versión: a1
   anchura: 64 bits
   reloj: 33MHz
   capacidades: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuración: driver=nouveau latency=0
   recursos: irq:49 memoria:c0000000-c0ffffff memoria:e0000000-efffffff memoria:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memoria:c1000000-c107ffff
  *-display
   descripción: VGA compatible controller
   producto: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
   fabricante: Intel Corporation
   id físico: 2
   información del bus: pci@0000:00:02.0
   versión: 09
   anchura: 64 bits
   reloj: 33MHz
   capacidades: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuración: driver=i915 latency=0
   recursos: irq:47 memoria:c1400000-c17fffff memoria:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:5000(size=64)
```

Comment: did you run `sensors-detect` answered `y` and saved /write it at the end of a proccess?

Comment: Try [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/114490/178596). Also, what is the output of `sudo lshw -C display,cpu`?

Comment: Joker, I've only run sensors-detect. I will prove what you say.
Wilf I will prove what you say too and I will tell you as I was.

Comment: I've been testing a HDD with Windows 8.1 and is not heated. The low temperature even the 50º C. I will change the HDD by the SDD that is where I have Ubuntu and test what you have told me (Joker and Wilf)

Comment: If `sensors-detect` doesn't detect your hardware, then... your hardware isn't supported.

Comment: Also: My machine is currently running at 61°C with 10% CPU usage.  It goes to 72°C at 50% and 78°C at 100% and 91°C with the CPU and GPU running at 100%.  As long as you don't get to the critical stage (105°C) you're fine!

Comment: Fabby thanks for the input. It may be that my laptop's temperature is normal.

Comment: Wilf the link what you say me doesn't work. Thanks.

Comment: Edit with result sudo lshw -C display,cpu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My machine's *CPU sensor* is currently running at 61 °C with 10 % CPU usage.

It goes up to 72 °C at 50 % and 78 °C at 100 %  CPU usage.

If both GPU and CPU are running at 100 % the *internal sensor* even goes up to to 91 °C

As long as your *CPU Sensor* doesn't get to the [critical stage for your processor](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/core/core-technical-resources.html) you're fine …  **:-)**

Comment: As you've never accepted an answer before: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: I installed the nvidia-331 but the problem is the same. Although I can lower the temperature slightly if you only work with Intel graphics card.
That said, I accepted the answer by the temperature is normal but working with the Nvidia card is note that the temperature rises more and no matter which drivers are installed. Thanks to all.

Comment: Try [this Q&A](http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers) then to get the latest nVidia drivers. I'm on 352.21 and they run a bit cooler then 331!  ;-)

Comment: P.S. Don't expect miracles: on the low end of the scale you can gain 20°C, but on the high scale it's 87-88°C now. (5°C cooler running games: full CPU/GPU usage)

Comment: Your processor shouldn't be going too high on those temps. Maybe you should try reinstalling the processor drivers. [Check this one for intel](http://askubuntu.com/a/767127/494131)

Comment: @GeorgeRappel Edited.  Worthy of an upvote now?  **:-)**

Answer (score 0):

Nvidia proprietary driver is not installed according to your output.

You have hybrid graphics and both adapter always work.

That is the cause of overheating.

Install the driver by running

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-331 nvidia-prime
```

and reboot.

You will be able to switch adapters in Nvidia Settings program.
If you switch to Intel, power consumption and heating must be minimal.

Comment: I installed the nvidia-331 but the problem is the same. Although I can lower the temperature slightly if you only work with Intel graphics card.

Answer (score 0):

## Adjust the fan speed with [nbfc](https://github.com/hirschmann/nbfc)

My laptop is an Acer Aspire E5-573G nothing else worked to control its CPU fan, but [nbfc](https://github.com/hirschmann/nbfc/wiki/First-steps). I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. The exact profile for my model is missing, but nbfc worked fine with another similar profile (Acer Aspire E5-575G). If you don't know which profile to use, you can try:
`mono nbfc.exe config -r`

Also I edit the default profile to turn the fan policy more agressive. So you can edit one for your machine, too.