# 16.04 - How To Purge Intel Default Drivers & Reinstall Intel Graphic Drivers

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics, 16.04

I posted [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763617/graphic-issues-after-ubuntu-16-04-upgrade) as I am encountering display problems after upgrading Ubuntu 15.10 to 16.04. I went into 'additional drivers' & noticed this:

[image]

I was wondering whether purging the current drivers & 'reinstalling' them again would help detect the graphic hardware I have on my system. For info, my system is a Lenovo X220 Thinkpad:
i5 2420M 
6Gb RAM
Onboard Graphic Card

Any suggestions would be great help. Many thanks,

Comment: It not clear the problem is caused by anything related to the Intel's graphics driver. There is also not much to reinstall, as far as "them" goes.

Answer (score 35):

I had a similar issue, and this worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-intel xserver-xorg-core
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

Followed by a reboot. Was having many irritating graphics crashes before, none since. It oddly didn't make Ubuntu recognise the device, but at least I'm not getting crashes now.

Adapted from original solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80914/how-reinstall-the-default-graphics-drivers).

Comment: Thanks Sam. I ended up reinstalling Ubuntu 16.04, which went fine. Upgrading Ubuntu seemed to have caused the problems. Now its working fine. I cant test your solution as I do not have the problem anymore so Im not sure whether to accept it to help others or upvote & leave the question open (have upvoted regardless).

Comment: Since yesterday I am [no longer able to log on to any DE](http://askubuntu.com/questions/806242/16-04-there-is-only-the-wallpaper-after-logging-in) in a laptop with a Sky Lake card and I suspect it is also a drivers issue. Unfortunately, reinstalling Xorg as you suggest did not fix my problem.

Comment: This worked for me after installing ubuntu-desktop over kubuntu (16.10)

Comment: This solved my error where the Intel processor fan not being detected by Ubuntu, thanks.

Comment: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-org` returns not installed error on 16.04 LTS for me...

Comment: This helped a lot to get rid of display glitches that I had forever with Ubuntu and my Intel graphics. But I notice that my CPU fan is spinning like crazy now.

Comment: @Erik xserver-xorg, not sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-org

Answer (score 0):

Using an updated gcc (6.2.0) and a newer kernel (4.8) was helpful for me. I couldn't upgrade to 16.04 from 14.04 and couldn't risk destroying a system I've built for years. Looks like I'm going to be building my Ubuntu software manually from now on..