# No ACPI Bus Error

Tags: drivers, 16.04, graphics, intel-graphics

After updating from 14.04 to 16.04, I noticed my computer running a lot slower. Googling suggested maybe updating the graphics drivers would help. I went into the drivers screen and selected the Intel one as in the screenshot in the question below (I have Intel HD 4000 on the laptop I'm using ATM):

[16.04 - How To Purge Intel Default Drivers & Reinstall Intel Graphic Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763672/16-04-how-to-purge-intel-default-drivers-reinstall-intel-graphic-drivers)

Unfortunately, now when I boot up I get a 'No ACPI video bus found' error and it dumps me into Emergency Mode. I've tried restarting in low graphics mode via Recovery Mode, but that launches a dialog with radio buttons which I can't interact with at all- no mouse, keyboard does nothing. I've tried reinstalling the video drivers as in the thread I linked, but no luck there either.

Is there any way to just roll back to my old settings? Or to switch my drivers back from the command-line? I'd rather not have to spend several hours reinstalling.